# Do any words rhyme with ‘doll’ in American English?

Tags: american-english, rhymes

Since *doll–dole* merged in British English but not in American English, what are other examples of words that rhyme with *doll* in American English?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English/%C9%92l

This page is non-sense, I haven't found any words in my dialect that rhyme with *doll*, at least words I know. I don't know what a *vol* is, for example.

Could I get a list of words that rhyme with *doll* for Americans?

Comment: Since you just answered your own question below, should this be closed?

Comment: What do you mean, _doll/dole merged in BrE_? Those words are distinct. (Not that it matters for this question since you're asking about AmE; but perhaps that phrase can be omitted or revised.)

Comment: Are you looking for a rhyme with a rounded vowel or with an unrounded vowel? And *which* Americans do you mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is open-ended and there is no real problem to be solved.

Comment: Does Roald Dahl rhyme?

Comment: Did you think *doll* rhymes with *dole* in British English because *doll* rhymes with *poll*? It does, but *poll* is not a homonym of *pole*; it's pronounced to rhyme with *doll*.

Comment: @PeterShor There are a small number of Cockney speakers for whom [*doll* and *dole* are indeed homophones.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Doll%E2%80%93dole_merger) But nowhere near enough to say that they've "merged in British English."

Comment: @PeterShor In BrE *poll* is usually pronounced like *pole,* but *doll* does not rhyme with *dole.* *Poll* might be pronounced like *doll* in the term "deed poll" because the documented is *polled* (cut straight and not indented like an indenture), and when it means "hornless animal", but both of those uses are specific (and for animals it's rare to obsolete).

Answer (score 1):

## *Dahl, loll, Sol, cabal, Nepal, halal, phaal*

I can’t say for sure because I don’t know *which*
Americans you’re asking about, nor which sounds,
either.  But I can give some parameters to
constrain the possibilities.

One thing to get out of the way first. I know of no merger of *doll* with *dole*
anywhere, since the latter still has the GOAT
phoneme in any mainstream English dialect I’m
aware of, but the former does not. And *dole* may even become bisyllabic with pre-L breaking as in [ˈdowəl], just like you can hear happen with [*cold*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/cold) in some speakers.  That never happens with *doll*.

---

## /ɒ/ is a marginal phoneme in American English

The rhymeset you pointed to is only for [/ɒl/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English/%C9%92l) rhymes, not for
[/ɔl/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English/%C9%94%CB%90l)
rhymes or even for
[/ɑl/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English/%C9%91%CB%90l)
rhymes. The problem is that /ɒ/ is a marginal phoneme at best in American English. It tends to collapse into either of the other two in many speakers, whether in production or in perception. Even those of us who have it may consider it a mere allophone, as in CLOTH–THOUGHT where the first has [ɒ] and the second [ɔ], but both are still /ɔ/ phonemically for lack of minimal pairs between those two.

See, however,
all the ways that
[*salt*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/salt) and [*all*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/all)
pan out in the real world of global English.

Many and possibly even “most” Americans pronounce *doll* with the
**unrounded** low back vowel so /dɑl/. This makes the given name *Dolly* sound much like Salvador *Dalí*’s surname (apart from the stress). While the common pronunciation is easily encountered across nearly all regions of America, other patterns *do* exist.

A very
small minority (such as in the Los Angeles area) would actually rhyme an unrounded *doll*
with an equally unrounded *all, ball, fall, hall, tall,
Paul, Saul*. But most of us could not because we all
have rounded vowels for those words save perhaps for
*doll* alone.

That said, I do believe I’ve heard people who say *Sol*
with an unrounded vowel, unlike *Saul* which rhymes with rounded *Paul*.

Other Americans certainly do say *doll* with a
**rounded** phoneme, so /dɔl/.  But the rounded
one varies somewhat in roundedness by region,
speaker, and utterance, generally between [dɔɫ]
and [dɒɫ] with no change in the underlying
phoneme. If you want a match for rounded *doll*,
then certainly *install* /ɪnˈstɔl/ and similar
words like *appall* are obvious choices.

It’s possible that those Americans who have
**unrounded** *doll* also have **unrounded**
[*Dall sheep*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dall_sheep).
But it might be that only one of those is
**unrounded** and not the other.  There’s too much
variation. Even words like *Nepal* vary in the
roundedness of their stressed vowel.

There is an imported loanword from Bengali that is
not usually pronounced with a **rounded** vowel,
so if you need a match for **unrounded** *doll*
then a [*phall*
curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phall)
(Bengali: ফাল), also spelt *fall, faal, phaal,
fahl,* or *fal*, might be a perfect rhyme.

A less exotic match for **unrounded** *doll* could
be *cabal*, but only for the majority who say
/kəˈbɑl/ with a back vowel not for the minority
who say /kəˈbæl/ with a front vowel.  Another
imported loanword that might work as a rhyme for **unrounded** *doll*
would be
[*halal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halal), at
least in those who say /həˈlɑl/ rather than
/həˈlæl/.  Same problem as with *cabal*, you see.
But I don’t know that I ever hear anybody using
the front vowel of *cat* and *prat* in those words
these days, the same one as the stressed vowel of the noun *ally*.

In a comment Yosef Baskin came up with perhaps a more natural rhyme for unrounded *doll*: unrounded *loll*, the verb meaning per the OED:

> *intransitive*. (The chief current sense.) To lean idly; to recline or rest in a relaxed attitude, supporting oneself against something. Also with *about, back, out*.

So like if you’re going to loll about the house all day doing nothing.

Comment: For *some* Cockney speakers, there is in fact a *doll-dole* merger; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Doll–dole_merger). This is (as I recall) ultimately due to the pervasive L-vocalization found in such dialects.

Comment: What's important is that in (many accents of) BrE, /ɒ/ is generally much shorter than either /ɑ/ or /ɔ/; Geoff Lindsey's transcription system reflects this. Compare your favorite dictionary's British pronunciation of *balm* and *bomb.*

Comment: @alphabet Vowel length is not part of the dialect he asked about, though. American English doesn't do that.

Comment: I know. I just mean that, to avoid confusion, your claim that "/ɒ/ is a marginal phoneme" should probably be qualified with an "in American English."

Comment: AmE: **loll** and **Sol**, my uncle's name. And Jamaican English: "**All** the good cheeldrun" (pronounced **Ahhhl**.)

Comment: @alphabet Edited to add.

Comment: @YosefBaskin *Loll* is a marvelous choice! (I did mention *Sol*, but I bet there are people who confuse it with *Saul*.)

Comment: Moll, as in a gangter's girlfriend.../

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=doll&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y

Out of this list, I can say that I definitely rhyme cabal with doll as well as foreign-origin words like Nepal and riyal